# find のパスに変数を指定したい

Tags: bash, shellscript

お疲れ様です。

本題ですが以下のようなコードがあるとします。

```
#!/bin/bash

file_name=test.txt

while read line; do
    dir=${line}

    while read red; do
         echo "動作確認:${red}"
     done < <(find ${dir} -type f)

done<${file_name}
```

これを実行すると「find: ‘ディレクトリ名’: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません」というエラーが出ます。

これを解決するにはどうすればよろしいでしょうか？

補足：
test.txt の中にはディレクトリパスが書いてあります。
それを「find」のパスに指定し、そのディレクトリ以下のファイルを検索したいです。

```
#!/bin/bash
    dir="ディレクトリパス"
    while read red; do
         echo "動作確認:${red}"
    done < <(find ${dir} -type f)
```

上記のように書くと上手くいきます。

エラーメッセージを見ると「'」かなにかがくっついてしまってるっぽいのですが、対処法が分かりません。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 問題ないように思います。このコードの実現しようとしているのが、「test.txtに記述されているパスにファイルが存在していれば動作確認を、さもなくばfindコマンドがエラーを吐く」ということのように見えます。

Comment: エラーメッセージの `find: ‘ディレクトリ名’` ですが、「ディレクトリ名」の部分は実際には存在するディレクトリ名が入っている、ということですか？

Comment: 手元でテストしてみたところ`test.txt`内で`${HOME}`や`${XDG_CACHE_HOME}`といった環境変数を使っているとエラーが出るようです。そこでお使いの`test.txt`の内容も質問内に加えていただけますか？

Comment: 実際の`text.txt`を見ないと何とも言えないのであくまでも一般論ですが、`read` には必ず`-r`オプションを付けるように習慣づけて下さい。また、`dir="$line"` や `find "$dir"` においては変数参照をダブルクォートで囲むことを忘れないでください。（もちろんダブルクォートで囲んではいけない場合もあるのですがそれは別途）ただしこれだけでは`dir="ディレクトリパス"`でうまくいく理由がわからないので、他に原因があるのかも知れません。そのためには`text.txt`をエラーが再現可能な最小構成で投稿していただくのが良いかと思います。

Comment: エラーに書かれてるとおりに、存在しないディレクトリが指定されてる可能性をまず確認したいのですが、書かれてる内容だと判別つきません。可能なら 実際のディレクトリ、ファイルの構造、および test.txt の中身を 具体的な内容を記載してもらえませんか？

Answer (score 1):

`find`(1) は指定された走査対象のパスが存在しないとそのような警告を表示します。`find` に渡す前に存在するかどうか検査すればよいだけですね。

```sh
#!/bin/bash

exec <dir.txt
while IFS= read -r d; do
  [[ -d $d ]] || continue
  find "$d" -type f -exec sh -c 'for file in "$@"; do echo "動作確認:$f"; done' sh {} +
done
```

Answer (score -1):

`find`コマンドの部分を`()`ではなく``` `` ```(バッククォート)でくくってみてください。
該当箇所だけ抜粋すると…

```
while read red; do
    echo "動作確認:${red}"
done < `find ${dir} -type f`
```

**実行環境**
bash 3.2
RHEL 5.11